# Does Microsoft Family Safety require an "adult" or admin account on each device?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, microsoft-family-safety

I have built a gaming PC for my son and want to install Windows 10 Pro from an USB stick now. We both have Microsoft accounts, and I want to limit my son's internet access (e.g. filter adult sites) and screen time using Microsoft Family Safety.

Do I have to install Windows using my name and login credentials, or can my son be the computer's sole user?

On our other computers the adults in our family have been the first users, before our son began to use them using his account, but this computer will only be used by my son, and I don't understand who has to be defined as the "owner" during installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to install Windows using my name and login credentials, or
> can my son be the computer's sole user?

You must install Windows 10 as an administrator, and also to install most software.

However, once set up and complete, add your son as a standard user with his own Microsoft Account.

Your account will still be the Owner Account. Each Computer must have an Owner / Administrator Account and that person can add accounts as needed.

That accomplishes your goals as you set them out.

Good luck.